# How to solve for $y$ in an equation, without explicitly deriving the answer of $x$ first?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Came across this in a math puzzle book.
Given the following equations.

$y=x^3$ and

$x^2 + 5x + 25 = 0$

what steps do I use to derive $y$ ?
(the answer for $y$ is $125$ and there is no need to get the answer for $x$.)

Comment: Hint: Do you know the formula for the difference of cubes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x^2 = -25 - 5x$, so

$$
x^3 = x ( -25 - 5x ) = -25x - 5 x^2 = - 25x -5 (-25 - 5x) = 125 - 25x + 25 x = 125.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Handsome Method:

$x^2 + 5x + 25 = 0\quad \ldots(1)$

Let, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is the roots of the quadratic equation.

$\therefore \alpha+\beta=-5$ and $\alpha\beta=25$

Now, $\alpha^3+\beta^3{=(\alpha+\beta)^3-3\alpha\beta(\alpha+\beta)\\=-125+375\\=250}$

Given, $y=x^3;\quad \therefore y=\alpha^3$ and $y=\beta^3$

$2y=\alpha^3+\beta^3=250\quad\therefore y=\frac{250}2=125$

---

Straight forward method:

Solve equation:

To solve the quadratic equation $x^2 + 5x + 25 = 0$, we can use the quadratic formula:

$
x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$

In our equation $x^2 + 5x + 25 = 0$, we have $a = 1, b = 5,\text{and}\ c = 25$. Plugging these values into the quadratic formula, we get:

$
x = \frac{-5 \pm \sqrt{5^2 - 4(1)(25)}}{2(1)}
= \frac{-5 \pm \sqrt{-75}}{2}=\frac{-5 \pm \sqrt{75}i}{2}
$

Find, $y=x^3=125$